# Check Fortran libraries using SCons

Tags: scons

I know there is exist option for C to check the existing libraries using conf.CheckLib . 
        
        `env=Environment()
        conf=Configure(env)
        if not conf.CheckLib('lapack'):
            print 'Did not find Lapack, exiting!'
        Exit(1)`

How do I modify it for Fortran libraries

Answer (score 1):

You have to roll your own `CheckFortranLib()`, based on the actual definition of `CheckLib()` in the source files `SConf.py` and `Conftest.py`.

If you succeed in this, please consider contributing your code to the [SCons contrib repo](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons-contrib). It would help the SCons project a lot.